Running Wordpress on subfolder of Next.js
My marketing and landing pages are on nextjs and want run my blog under /articles where I want to use WordPress
What's the best way to get this setup going?
I am using vercel to host my nextjs app.
Not sure how to run the WordPress in a subdomain and also vercel doesn't support WordPress.
